# How can I show a custom user edit form?

Tags: forms, 9

I need to show only a few fields on the user edit form: username, email, and password.

I want to have a user edit form on a different page & URL and not the default form where users shall be able to edit the username, password, and email address of their own account

How do I show only these fields and theme the page?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**For the Drupal user form changes:**

Try with `HOOK_form_form_id_alter()` in .module

```
    function MYMODULE_form_user_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      // Your code...
    }
```

or you can try `HOOK_form_alter()`

```
    function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
        // Your code...
      }
    }
```

e.g

```
function MODULENAME_form_user_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

      if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer users')) {

        $form['field_organization_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';  
        $form['field_organization_reference']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';    

      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to the question, Apologies for not mentioning all the details earlier. I want to have a user edit form on a different page & url and not the default form where users shall be able to edit username, password and email address of the their own account.